# Iterate through a list and use values in complex queries Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models

Am having a request in the following design :- example.com/?param1=blah&param1=blah1....param1=blahn. Notice that I want to have param1 with several parameters. Now to capture the values of the parameter param1, I do the following

```
searchQery = request.GET.getlist('param1')
```

where I get a list with values for param1. I want to use a complex query

```
for item searchQuery:
      val = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(item__startswith=searchQuery[0])| Q(item__startswith=searchQuery[1])| Q(item__startswith=searchQuery[2])) all the way to searchQuery[n]
```

In short I want to iterate through the values of the list, dynamically and am currently lost there.

Comment: Why you don't use "__in". here is a simple example in this context. val = MyModel.objects.filter(item__in=list)

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import or_
val = MyModel.objects.filter(reduce(or_,(Q(item__startswith=x) for x in searchQuery)))
```

Use `reduce` to combine a generated sequence of `Q` expressions.